# Is making asynchronous HTTP requests possible with PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I have a PHP script that needs to download several files from a remote server. At the moment I just have a loop downloading and processing the files with cURL, which means that it doesn't start downloading one file until the previous one is finished - this increases the script run time significantly.

Would it be possible to start several instances of cURL, for example, to asynchronously download these files at the same time without waiting for the previous one to finish? If so, how would this be accomplished?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562037/php-multithreading-problem

Comment: i would put the curl in its own file and call the file with exec("nohup php curl.php" . $file); they will all run simultaneously no add ons needed

Comment: As far as PHP is concerned: https://github.com/rdlowrey/Artax

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes.

There is the [multirequest PHP library](https://github.com/barbushin/multirequest) (or see: [archived Google Code project](https://code.google.com/archive/p/multirequest/)). It's a multi-threaded CURL library.

As another solution, you could write a script that does that in a language that supports threading, like Ruby or Python. Then, just call the script with PHP. Seems rather simple.

Comment: I see there are a few of these libraries available - which one is the most widely used?

Comment: @MarathonStudios - Your comment is a completely different question.

Comment: I am not sure. Popularity never seemed to much as matter as quality to me. Maybe examine the code of the library, and use that as the main factor of your decision.

Comment: @Jared, it's the natural follow up to my question, which bl00d just answered :]

Comment: As a side note, I have added another possible solution, you may enjoy it.

Comment: @MarathonStudios - Not really.

Comment: @bl00d, I had considered that, but I wanted to see if there were any solutions in PHP. Has the Multirequest library you linked to been reliable?

Answer (score 21):

Check out [curl-easy](https://github.com/stil/curl-easy). It supports both blocking and not-blocking requests in parallel or single request at once. Also, it is unit-tested, unlike many simple or buggy libraries.

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. The library has it's own test suite so I'm pretty confident it is robust.

Also, check out example of use below:

```
<?php
// We will download info about 2 YouTube videos:
// http://youtu.be/XmSdTa9kaiQ and
// http://youtu.be/6dC-sm5SWiU

// Init queue of requests
$queue = new cURL\RequestsQueue;
// Set default options for all requests in queue
$queue->getDefaultOptions()
    ->set(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5)
    ->set(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set callback function to be executed when request will be completed
$queue->addListener('complete', function (cURL\Event $event) {
    $response = $event->response;
    $json = $response->getContent(); // Returns content of response
    $feed = json_decode($json, true);
    echo $feed['entry']['title']['$t'] . "\n";
});

$request = new cURL\Request('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/XmSdTa9kaiQ?v=2&alt=json');
$queue->attach($request);

$request = new cURL\Request('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/6dC-sm5SWiU?v=2&alt=json');
$queue->attach($request);

// Execute queue
$queue->send();
```

Comment: Your library is absolutely remarkable. Thanks for it! I was about to give up and only then, I found it. Greaaaaaat job, mate!

Comment: @jreed121 no, actually it doesn't. Callback functions are executed sequentially, so there is no risk of accessing objects simultaneously.

Comment: Nice. Honestly, I get the concept of TS, but I'm still pretty ignorant on the details. All I know for sure is that I need to make a crapload of API calls to different sites, and this particular site is on shared hosting that is not TS. Thanks again for sharing this, and for the quick reply!

Answer (score 1):

The library of **@stil** is so, so cool. Many thanks to him!

Still, I have written nice utility function that makes it very easy to get asynchronously content from multiple URLs (APIs in my case) and to return them without losing information which is which.

You simply run it by passing *key => value* array as an input and it returns *key => response* array as result :- )

```
/** 
     * This function runs multiple GET requests parallely.<br />
     * @param array $urlsArray needs to be in format:<br />
     * <i>array(<br />
     * [url_unique_id_1] => [url_for_request_1],<br />
     * [url_unique_id_2] => [url_for_request_2],<br />
     * [url_unique_id_3] => [url_for_request_3]<br />
     * )</i><br />
     * e.g. input like:<br />
     *  <i>array(<br />
     * &nbsp; "myemail@gmail.com" =>
     * &nbsp; "http://someapi.com/results?search=easylife",<br />
     * &nbsp; "michael@gmail.com" =>
     * &nbsp; "http://someapi.com/results?search=safelife"<br />
     * )</i>
     * @return array An array where for every <i>url_unique_id</i> response to this request 
     * is returned e.g.<br />
     * <i>array(<br />
     * &nbsp; "myemail@gmail.com" => <br />
     * &nbsp; "Work less, enjoy more",<br />
     * &nbsp; "michael@gmail.com" => <br />
     * &nbsp; "Study, work, pay taxes"<br />
     * )</i>
     *  */
    public function getResponsesFromUrlsAsynchronously(array $urlsArray, $timeout = 8) {
        $queue = new \cURL\RequestsQueue;

        // Set default options for all requests in queue
        $queue->getDefaultOptions()
                ->set(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout)
                ->set(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // =========================================================================
        // Define some extra variables to be used in callback

        global $requestUidToUserUrlIdentifiers;
        $requestUidToUserUrlIdentifiers = array();

        global $userIdentifiersToResponses;
        $userIdentifiersToResponses = array();

        // =========================================================================

        // Set function to be executed when request will be completed
        $queue->addListener('complete', function (\cURL\Event $event) {

            // Define user identifier for this url
            global $requestUidToUserUrlIdentifiers;
            $requestId = $event->request->getUID();
            $userIdentifier = $requestUidToUserUrlIdentifiers[$requestId];

            // =========================================================================

            $response = $event->response;
            $json = $response->getContent(); // Returns content of response

            $apiResponseAsArray = json_decode($json, true);
            $apiResponseAsArray = $apiResponseAsArray['jobs'];

            // =========================================================================
            // Store this response in proper structure
            global $userIdentifiersToResponses;
            $userIdentifiersToResponses[$userIdentifier] = $apiResponseAsArray;
        });

        // =========================================================================

        // Add all request to queue
        foreach ($urlsArray as $userUrlIdentifier => $url) {
            $request = new \cURL\Request($url);
            $requestUidToUserUrlIdentifiers[$request->getUID()] = $userUrlIdentifier;
            $queue->attach($request);
        }

        // =========================================================================

        // Execute queue
        $queue->send();

        // =========================================================================

        return $userIdentifiersToResponses;
    }
```

Comment: I'm glad you made use of it. But there is simpler solution to track "which request is which". `$request = new \cURL\Request($url); $request->_myId = 1;` and then check on `complete` event: `$event->request->_myId`. It's a popular problem, so I'll see how to implement it in library without declaring dynamic properties in request object.

Comment: Ah, yeah. Well, that's a bit easier, actually I thought about it, but like you said, I wanted to avoid dynamic field being assigned to an external class. Thanks for the tip and for the library! :- )

Answer (score 1):

For PHP5.5+, **[mpyw/co](https://github.com/mpyw/co)** is the ultimate solution. It works as if it is [tj/co](https://github.com/tj/co) in JavaScript.

#### Example

Assume that you want to download specified multiple GitHub users' avatars. The following steps are required for each user.

1. Get content of http://github.com/mpyw (GET HTML)
2. Find `<img class="avatar" src="...">` and request it (GET IMAGE)

`---`: Waiting my response
`...`: Waiting other response in parallel flows

Many famous `curl_multi` based scripts already provide us the following flows.

```
        /-----------GET HTML\  /--GET IMAGE.........\
       /                     \/                      \ 
[Start] GET HTML..............----------------GET IMAGE [Finish]
       \                     /\                      /
        \-----GET HTML....../  \-----GET IMAGE....../
```

However, this is not efficient enough. Do you want to reduce worthless waiting times `...`?

```
        /-----------GET HTML--GET IMAGE\
       /                                \            
[Start] GET HTML----------------GET IMAGE [Finish]
       \                                /
        \-----GET HTML-----GET IMAGE.../
```

Yes, it's very easy with mpyw/co. For more details, visit the repository page.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 7.0 & Apache 2.0, as said in [PHP exec Document](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#refsect1-function.exec-notes),  redirecting the output, by adding " **&> /dev/null &**" at the end of the command, could makes it running on background, just remember to wrap the command correctly.

```
$time = microtime(true);
$command = '/usr/bin/curl -H \'Content-Type: application/json\' -d \'' . $curlPost . '\' --url \'' . $wholeUrl . '\' >> /dev/shm/request.log 2> /dev/null &';
exec($command);
echo (microtime(true) - $time) * 1000 . ' ms';
```

Above works well for me, takes only 3ms, but following won't work, takes 1500ms.

```
$time = microtime(true);
$command = '/usr/bin/curl -H \'Content-Type: application/json\' -d \'' . $curlPost . '\' --url ' . $wholeUrl;
exec($command . ' >> /dev/shm/request.log 2> /dev/null &');
echo (microtime(true) - $time) * 1000 . ' ms';
```

In total, adding " &> /dev/null &" at the end of your command may helps, just remember to WRAP your command properly.