# Fastest way to Fire and Forget a JSON POST in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm currently in the process of building/implementing a logging system for a website I'm working on that's in PHP. The way the logging system works is I send a JSON request to localhost and that json gets logged (basically, anyway.

**My question is:**

what's the fastest way I can make a quick fire and forget call with a JSON POST? Is there a way to fire and forget with cURL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453192/is-making-asynchronous-http-requests-possible-with-php

Comment: If you're just wanting to log page requests why don't you use the raw webserver log files or something like Google Analytics?

Comment: I'm not just logging page requests. I'm doing application logging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it: you could use the [curl_multi](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) functionality of the `php_curl` extension, which allows you to send asynchronous HTTP requests using cURL, but this requires that extension. [GuzzlePHP](http://guzzlephp.org) provides a large wrapper around much of the functionality of cURL, including the `curl_multi` features if you are looking for an object-oriented approach.
 PHP's sockets also support asynchronous communications, a library which implements this for the HTTP protocol is available [here](https://github.com/rdlowrey/Artax) [the client is written in "pure" PHP and has no dependency on cURL but supports asynchronous requests and fully complies with the HTTP 1.1 spec].

Comment: Another option is to use a non-blocking `system()` call that calls a command-line cURL program or wget.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a fire and forget logging solution you might want to look at something that uses UDP protocol like Graylog.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a small image that hits a PHP script. The php script logs the hit and returns a tiny 1x1 transparent GIF. Then the logging will happen after the page loads.

Comment: That means the client performs the task, not PHP. It also makes it hard to transfer data to be logged. This approach is unreliable.

Comment: I assumed you were just trying to log the page hit.

Comment: Always dangerous to assume!