# How to perform some script after closing the calling file?

Tags: php

If `operations.php` performs some operations and is called by `caller.php` this way:

```
$call_URL = "http://localhost/operations.php";
$call = file_get_contents($call_URL);
```

Say, `operations.php` hasn't done performing actions by the time `caller.php` ends. Will it continue working after `caller.php` is closed or redirected using a `header()` function? What if I need it to work after that? Maybe cURL will help?

Comment: This stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453192/is-making-asynchronous-http-requests-possible-with-php tells you how to do this using curl

Answer (score 3):

The called file *will* have ended by the time the caller ends. `file_get_contents` blocks until it has received a complete response from `operations.php`.

Use a cron job or a queue/worker system if you need to get work done in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You can say PHP to continue execution even if the connection is interrupted by giving `true` to [`ignore_user_abort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php).