# Asynchronous requestAction

Tags: cakephp, asynchronous

Pleeeeease **help me**... :- )

*"You are my only hope".*

I need to execute an action asynchronously several thousand times. The action is supposed to fetch email content from external API and it is located in the different controller, so I use *requestAction* to get it. When I get all the results, then these 1000 email contents are sent as 1000 emails during one request, using other API.

Unfortunately, when run sequentially, it takes a lof of time, so I need to run these request asynchronously.

My question is:
Can I execute

```
$this->requestAction($myUrl)
```

...parallelly? For example 100 requests at one time? I've seen a bit of asynchronous examples in PHP, but they all used static files and I need to preserve CakePHP structure to be able to use *requestAction*.

Thanks to all who can help!

*EDIT:* By the way, when I tried to run requests via *fopen($url, 'r');* and then *stream get contents* the efficiency was worse than worst, but maybe it could be improved. Don't know, but the *requestAction* seems to be definitely better option (I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason why you wouldn't use a shell for this? 
Please take a look at: [CakePHP Shells](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html)

"Deferred Execution" is probably what you are after here, basically you want to send one command not have the user waiting around for it? If so then you can use a Message Queue to handle this pretty easily.

We use CakeResque and Redis to send 1000's of emails and perform other API calls

[CakeResque - Deferred Processing for CakePHP](http://cakeresque.kamisama.me/)

There are other message queues that are available but this is really simple to get working and probably wont need much of a change to your code.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I wasn't able to find a solution that would use *requestAction*, but I was able to extract the code to a standalone php file, which then is processed using *include* method.

And the most interesting part, **asynchronous requests**, was done using great library called **cURL-easy** and with help of my utility function. You can read about it (how to install and how to use it) here:

[Is making asynchronous HTTP requests possible with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453192/is-making-asynchronous-http-requests-possible-with-php/28373491#28373491)