# how can i asynchronous call using php for the continue code execution?

Tags: php

How can I make async call in PHP means I can call a url of other domain in php code and its its execution did not stop and code execution continue? I would like same AJAX request but on server side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is making asynchronous HTTP requests possible with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453192/is-making-asynchronous-http-requests-possible-with-php)

Comment: ? Please try to be more specific

Comment: I have one domain http://xyz.php and one of page execute like xyz.php/test.php. In test.php i would like to call a other domain like abc.com/test1.php.If this test1.php execution time a lot means response time (30 Sec).I would like that if test.php execute remaining part of code not wait from response of test1.php.is it possible in php ?

Comment: I think there are answer :- https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/blob/master/examples/CallAnyFunction.php

Answer (score 0):

You might think of cURL. Check cURL you can receive data by it from different domains.