# Count messages from multiple inbox using Mailinator API

Tags: php, arrays, api, curl, mailinator

Need some advice. I am playing around with Mailinator PHP API and I was wondering if it is possible to fetch message count from multiple inboxes of Mailinator. May be using an array of inboxnames? I have tried it with single inbox and it fetches fine but when I use array, It gives me message count of first inbox (In array) only. Below is the code i've tried for fetching single inbox.

```
include 'Mailinator.php';
$mailinator = new Mailinator('API_KEY_HERE');
$data = new Inbox();
$data = $mailinator->inbox(exampleinbox);
echo $data->count();
```

I am looking for something like this, but doesn't work!

```
include 'Mailinator.php';
$inboxes = array("inbox1", "inbox2", "inbox3");
$mailinator = new Mailinator('API_KEY_HERE');
$data = new Inbox();
$data = $mailinator->inbox($inboxes);
echo $data->count(0);
echo $data->count(1);
```

It would also be great if i can make an array from file.txt

Comment: Have you considered a simple loop using the code that works

Comment: You mean something like this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36406463/php-multiple-curl-urls-with-while-loop

Comment: No! I dont know Mailinator, but if a single pass works, why not wrap it in a `foreach($inboxes as $inbox)` and look at one at a time and then just add up the counts

Comment: It would be great if you can give me a demo code. In case you wish to check, I can give you api key

Comment: There you go, like I say its a bit of a guess so dont beat me up if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me, I dont know Mailinator, but, if this code works

```
include 'Mailinator.php';
$mailinator = new Mailinator('API_KEY_HERE');
$data = new Inbox();
$data = $mailinator->inbox(exampleinbox);
echo $data->count();
```

Then to get the same data from multiple inboxes why not simply do

```
include 'Mailinator.php';
$mailinator = new Mailinator('API_KEY_HERE');

$inboxes = array("inbox1", "inbox2", "inbox3");
$counts = [];

foreach ($inboxes as $inbox) {
    $data = new Inbox();    
    $data = $mailinator->inbox($inbox);

    $counts[] = ['inbox'=>$inbox, 'count'=>$data->count()]
}

// here you can convert to JSON String if you like

echo json_encode($counts);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for writing this but I am sorry but I guess there is a misinterpretation. I don't need a count of all mailboxes, I just need counts of individual inboxes in an array or json or anything.

Comment: Is that more like what you want

Comment: Yes. Just that I need message counts from inboxes in array.

Comment: Well maybe give me a slightly bigger clue, as I believe they are in an array. so help me by describing the array you want

Answer (score 0):

Yipee!! Got this working.

```
<?
// Created this Internal API Handler - api.php
$inbox = $_GET['inbox'];
include 'Mailinator.php';
$mailinator = new Mailinator('API_KEY_HERE');
$data = new Inbox();
$data = $mailinator->inbox($inbox);
$json = json_encode ($data->count());
echo "$json";
?>
```

Then used some multi curl!

```
<?php

//Filename multi.php

function multiRequest($data, $options = array()) {

  // array of curl handles
  $curly = array();
  // data to be returned
  $result = array();

  // multi handle
  $mh = curl_multi_init();

  // loop through $data and create curl handles
  // then add them to the multi-handle
  foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

    $curly[$id] = curl_init();

    $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // post?
    if (is_array($d)) {
      if (!empty($d['post'])) {
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
      }
    }

    // extra options?
    if (!empty($options)) {
      curl_setopt_array($curly[$id], $options);
    }

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
  }

  // execute the handles
  $running = null;
  do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  } while($running > 0);


  // get content and remove handles
  foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
    $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
  }

  // all done
  curl_multi_close($mh);

  return $result;
}

?>
```

Then called this

```
<?php
require_once 'multi.php';
$data = array(
  'http://example.com/api.php?inbox=inbox1',
  'http://example.com/api.php?inbox=inbox2',
  'http://example.com/api.php?inbox=inbox3'
);
$r = multiRequest($data);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($r);

?>
```