# Can REST API calls to a remote API be made from a PHP page without affecting page load time?

Tags: php

Would like to know if this sample PHP page can be modified to avoid the page load delay of 10 seconds without affecting the functionality.

```
<html>
<head><title>Test Page</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Test Page </h1>
<?php 
 echo '<br/>';
 $post_url_prefix="https://httpbin.org/delay/10?ua=";
 // creating URL to post (sending user agent received at the server to sample remote API, currently remote API responds after 10 seconds configured in url)
 $post_url = $post_url_prefix . urlencode($_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT]);
 print_r($post_url);
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
// using php curl to post data
$cSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,$post_url);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$result=curl_exec($cSession);
curl_close($cSession);
?>
```

Currently the API server is adding a 10 second artificial delay before responding. Would like to know if there is a solution in which  this delay shouldn't get reflected in the page load time.

Please note that the question is whether it is feasible from the PHP "server side". This rules out solutions using JS, iframe, ajax etc. which requires the requests to be made from client browser.

Comment: Maybe if you do an asynch request: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453192/is-making-asynchronous-http-requests-possible-with-php

Comment: Fetch the data in the background and cache it somewhere, instead of requesting it fresh upon page load?

Comment: I wouldn't dismiss AJAX.. You can make the request to your 'PHP Server Side' that is just a proxy for the actual request you want to make.

Comment: Maybe it help a little if you flush before you do the cUrl: 
    ob_flush(); 
    flush();
This will send the output to the browser explicitly before the cUrl

Comment: @verhie I tried ob_flush() and flush(). But still, the page was loading slow.

Comment: No. curl_exec() will block until a response is received/completed. if you want to NOT block, then fetch the data separately via a client-side initiated ajax request back to your server, and that separate request does the curl stuff.

Comment: @JeffLambert , the reason why a solution with client-side support (like ajax) is not feasible is that the approach should work even when search engine crawlers or a curl/wget request also hit the website. These clients will not have support for ajax etc.

Answer (score 0):

That's not very clean, but you could close the current connection and send the data to the user browser and, after that, do the CURL call. That way the user won't have to wait for it.

Something like this would work:

```
<html>
<head><title>Test Page</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Test Page </h1>
<?php 
 echo '<br/>';
 $post_url_prefix="https://httpbin.org/delay/10?ua=";
 // creating URL to post (sending user agent received at the server to sample remote API, currently remote API responds after 10 seconds configured in url)
 $post_url = $post_url_prefix . urlencode($_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT]);
 print_r($post_url);
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
ob_end_clean();
header("Connection: close\r\n");
header("Content-Encoding: none\r\n");
header("Content-Length: 1");
ignore_user_abort(true);
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();

// At this point, the page has been sent in full to the user.
// Now, do the CURL request:

// using php curl to post data
$cSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,$post_url);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$result=curl_exec($cSession);
curl_close($cSession);
?>
```

Comment: Will that affect connection keep-alive ? Will connections which will otherwise be kept alive become closed because of this change ?

Comment: Yes it will affect keep-alive connections as the connection will be closed. If you want keep alive connections along with async curl request, you'll need to use a different approach (for example by invoking the command line in the background).