# Different concurrent requests to REST API

Tags: rest, curl, concurrency

I want to know how I can issue multiple, different cURL requests *concurrently* to a RESTful API, to test my application. I'm using a Maru RESTful API for Elixir, and my requests only differ in the GET arguments. My cURL requests look something like:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8880/path -G -d "data1=abc&data2=123&..."
```

where the values of `data1`, `data2` etc. differ. I would prefer some sort of a tool like [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html), the Apache HTTP server benchmarking tool, but [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) only allows concurrent requests of the same kind. I am trying to test my application for concurrent, differing responses to the different, concurrently issued cURL requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make your cURL requests [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453192/is-making-asynchronous-http-requests-possible-with-php), so they can run in the same time and when they are finished, a callback function is called. However, this will not necessarily solve your problem, since there is a chance that the remote API is using something like IIS, serving requests sequentially.